# How to fix this error while importing svg?

Tags: import

I'd like to import a svg in blender, but I got this error:

[image: http://imgur.com/H64a2Sa]

How to fix this?

Comment: Might be a good idea to use latest blender version.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Judging by the last line of the error message, it might be simplest to:

- make a copy of the svg,
- then open the copy in a text editor
- do a search for the string '297mm' and replace it with `297`.
- you might also see width described with *210mm*, also remove the *mm* there.
- Then save, then open the copy.

Incidentally, not all svg files will import OK.

Comment: It worked! It can also be loaded back on blender; it is just very very small. Maybe I should have exported it with different parameters... :P

Comment: Scale can be a nuisance, as long as the object proportions are OK no-one will get too upset.